# VB.NET GUI - TSQL dynamic SQL nightmare design

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, dynamic-sql

This is more of a design rather than implementation question. We have a VB.NET front end to our database. The current design is using table upon table of meta data to enforce a "NO SQL in the front end" policy. I view the things we do as worse than hard coding because we now have a nice smattering of STORED PROC spaghetti code. We have lots of dynamic SQL that is used to build the fully qualified names of tables that then get sent back to another STORED PROC that handles actual loading of flat text files for example.

```
    ID DATA_TABLE_NAME DATA_TABLE_SCHEMA PTR_TABLE_NAME PTR_TABLE_SCHEMA
    1  datatable            DBO            datatable_ptr       DBO
```

So we have a class that will grab the data table name and the table pointer and mash it into a class in the VB.NET front end that sends a full name like database.dbo.datatable which maps to database.dbo.datable_ptr and uses global temp tables to load the flat text files. Well someone added a row to this nasty little table of meta data and it BROKE THE VB.NET FRONT END! There has got to be a better way to do this but I'm not experienced enough to come up with a better general solution.

How on earth does a programmer emphasize code reuse and generic programming using T-SQL and VB.NET while keeping the code readable and maintainable? Does anyone have some recommendations on books with design patterns or a cook book that can point me to some more workable solution?

Comment: Ouch! Is this mainly a data entry app where you are looking to reuse/enforce Business Logic or more of a reporting app?  Unfortunately finding the solution will likely be much easier that getting it implemented. And then before you promise the moon to get buy-in you'd better read this <http://onstartups.com/tabid/3339/bid/2596/Why-You-Should-Almost-Never-Rewrite-Your-Software.aspx>

Comment: This is a data entry application that takes a dump of text files from another agency (once size fits none data) and then goes into our database for our simulations. The front end was meant to unify the 35+ apps my division used to load data into the database. Each Subject Matter Expert kind of had their own data "fiefdom" and the old apps where made by data analysts that had no training as software engineers or database administrators. I'm in charge of maintaining and enhancing this new "Master Loader" while we have contractors working on a new back end design.

Comment: If you are using SQL server I would take a good look at SQL Server Integration Services but I have not used it enough lately to recommend a good current source.

Comment: Not clear on what the original goal was. You mentioned kind of a slogan of "NO SQL in the front end". Why, what problem was that supposed to solve? Is there a middle tier between client and DB, or is the client calling stored procedures directly? In that case, the client actually is using SQL, so was the goal to avoid building dynamic SQL in the client? If the DB is merely a repository for flat files, why not just save the flat files on a network drive or in a simple key-value table in the DB? What purpose to all these extra layers of indirection serve?

Answer (score 1):

Before I begin my proposed solution I believe that I need to disclose some things first:

1) I **only** have a little over 2 years of professional programming experience.
2) I am shortsighted because I only have experience with the database that I use every day.
3) I have only worked with ONE (and the current) vb.Net/ TSQL company.

That said, here's what I would do given the following:

1) Your managers will most likely want to see some sort of quantifiable progress.
2) You are looking for a practical *method* as to how to approach this problem (what this proposed solution provides) that facilitates said quantifiable progress.
3) You need to maintain the "NO SQL in the front end" philosophy.
4) You need something scalable so when 35+ apps becomes 75+ apps you're still okay.

Solution:
1. Create a new database as if SQL was allowed in the front end (i.e. 'what you've been wanting').
2. Create a web service that will act as a go-between between the front-end (which cannot have SQL) and the database "you've always wanted". This will de-couple the problem. The database structure need not be obfuscated since it will be twice removed from the end user.

Method:
1) Initially, the dynamic SQL can be moved to the web service 'as is'. It can stay there as parts of the spaghetti are translated.  We can call this the "Master function", or 'the old way of doing things'.
2) Appoint a team leader for each application (or one leader per 5 applications, etc). Their responsibility will be to act as a liason in creating their portion of the web service. You will need to know what tables they need, and they will need to know the format you want when they create their web services.
3) Take on the applications one at a time:
   A) Set up the database tables that they need
   B) Create the web service to interface those tables with the front end
   C) Create the function calls from the front end to hit the web service(s). First trying the  new function that interfaces    with the new database tables, and then trying the Master function to interface with the database like it does now.

As the applications are switched over to utilize their 'personalized' web service functions the Master function should be doing less and less (i.e. you 
slowly stop using the spaghetti stored procedures). Also, as the creation of the web service (which, by the end of this may have as many contributors as 
applications) is decentralized, the work could pontentially go fairly quickly, and since the master function will be the first thing to get up and running, your
operation as a whole should still be able to do business as usual.